# Mongodb import export database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I want to import and restore the mogodb database from one machine to another

I have used

```
sudo mongodump --collection collection --db ppm_v2_development
```

But its getting empty folder
dump/ppm_v2_development/

[This](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongoexport/)
 is also not helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this slideshow [Backup, restore and repair database in mongo db linux file](http://www.slideshare.net/yourcanjou/backup-restore-and-repair-database-in-mongo-db-linux-file#btnNext)

Comment: mongorestore is not defined completely